# Ternary Operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm working with ternary operators and I need a little help. I'm converting a simple if-else statement but I have a simple syntax error that I cannot seem to figure out. I'm practicing an exercise on code academy and I error I'm getting is that the first line is undefined. 
Here is the original code :

```
if (food === "taco") {
  foodType = "Mexican";
} else {
  foodType = "other";  
}
```

This is my code. This first line is undefined but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
var food = prompt("Food type");
var food === "taco" ? "Mexican": "other";
```

Comment: @Bryan There is no var in java.

Comment: this line "var food = prompt("Food type");
" is completely unrelated to the question you have asked...

Comment: @MitchWheat How is that true and why would that matter? It provides us proof that `food` is a string and that the use of `===` is valid. I don't see how it's "completely unrelated"...

Comment: @ianpgall: see this bit: "Here is the original code"

Comment: @MitchWheat Yeah yeah, I'm betting the "original code" also has the `prompt`, it just wasn't included. I guess these things should be more consistent

Answer (score 7):

I think what you meant to do was:

```
foodType = (food === "taco") ? "Mexican": "other"
                   ^condition       ^true    ^false
```

**[MDN:  Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**

Answer (score 1):

Ternary syntax should look like this,

```
variableToBeSet = (condition) ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

in your problem,

```
foodtype = (food === "taco") ? "Mexican": "other";
```

Answer (score 0):

**boolean expression ? value1 : value2**

For example, the following if..then..else statement

```
boolean isSmiley = true;

 String mood = "";

 if (isSmiley == true)
 {
   mood = "I'm Happy!";
 }
 else
 {
   mood = "I'm Sad!";
 }
```

Now you can use ternary oprtation like below

```
 boolean isSmiley = true;
 String mood = (isSmiley == true)?"I'm Happy!":"I'm Sad!";
```